# Python Lambda Functions: return statusCode or status_code?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When using an AWS Lambda function through API Gateway in Python, are you supposed to call the HTTP response field "statusCode" or "status_code" ?

AWS recommends "statusCode":
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html

but in python, using the 'requests' library, the requests.Response object expects a different casing:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_response.asp

and doesn't manage to pick up the HTTP status code that I am returning from the lambda, like so:

```
return {
            "statusCode": 500,
            'message': "3rd party API call failed. Check server logs for details."
        }
```

When I run my tests, this yields:

> post_update_response.status_code =  **200**

> post_update_response.text:
> {"statusCode": 500, "message": "3rd party API call failed. Check
> server logs for details."}

Comment: The documentation says that you should write statusCOde: "500", with the value in quotes.  No sure if this matters, but it's worth a try.

Comment: What a specific Python library, `requests` in this case, does is not relevant.

Comment: I tried the quotes, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that API gateway either needs extra configuration (old way):
https://dikshit18.medium.com/mapping-api-gateway-with-lambda-output-e8ea9e435bbf

Lambda functions return statusCode just gets ignored and passed through as ordinary JSON (not http return code) unless you do this.

or you have to use Lambda Proxies (new way):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html

I'll post back if I can get it to work.